# React-Router open Link in new tab content is opening in same existing tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**I am using react-router for clicking button and opening different component in new tab button things are happening opposite means before clicking on that button that content is showing in the existing page without clicking that button and after clicking the button same content is showing as it is like first component for more insights check my code screenshot and output also**

1. index.js
   [image]
2. Globe.js
   [image]
3. Space.js
   [image]
4. Main App.js
   [image]
5. Output 1 before clicking the button
   [image]
6. After clicking the button
   [image]

can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i deleted app.js file and reference related to that and then did following**
[image]

[image]

[image]

thank you brother saurabh for guiding me ❤

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're still seeing the `Globe` component in a new tab is because `App` component will always be rendering as it is not dependent on any route.

You need to remove the `<App />` line from `index.js` file and instead add a new route inside `Switch` as shown below:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App} />
```